# How to force EF migrations to not apply WillCascadeOnDelete to database?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have next models:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Statement> Statements { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Criterion> Criteria { get; set; }
}

public class Statement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Criterion> Criteria { get; set; }
}

public class Criterion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And next cascade settings:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Criteria)
    .WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();

modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Statements)
    .WithRequired(x => x.Company)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();

modelBuilder.Entity<Statement>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Criteria)
    .WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

I use EF migrations for creating database. But if I apply the migrations, I have sql server error "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths".

Yes, I have two path for removing criteria:

Company->Statement->Criterion

Company->Criterion

But I have no any criteria with StatementId and CompanyId simultaneously. That's why if I turn off migrations, removing company works perfectly.

I try solve this problem by forcing EF migrations not to apply WillCascadeOnDelete to database. How can I do that?